# Woocommerce get total on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to get Woo-commerce order total on cart page.[image: Woo-commerce total price on cart page]

Comment: you can use this $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); to get total on cart page.

Comment: It will gives subtotal price not total price. I have mentioned in attachment for total.

Comment: actually when i add some custom tax with order on checkout page without page refresh using ajax, yes i do like subtotal $50 and custom tax $5 then total would be $15, but without page refresh how can i get total price for update total.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$cart` to access the cart object.

Use `$cart_total` to access the cart total after all the calculations.

```
add_action("woocommerce_cart_contents", "get_cart");
function get_cart()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    // Will get you cart object
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart;
    // Will get you cart object
    $cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
}
```

The cart total echoed here will be displayed above Cart table.

Refer to the [WC_Cart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html) class documentation for more help.

Comment: It will gives subtotal price not total price. I have mentioned in attachment for total.

Answer (score 0):

As order total in checkout is variable, i.e. is sum of added tax or shipping costs, you can get it after the order is set. You can access it when place order button is clicked. By `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` action hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'get_total_cost', 20, 1 );
function get_total_cost($order){
    $total = $order->get_total();
}
```

Comment: Any way to get checkout total before the order is placed (created)?